# FAILED status in Org mode in addition to DONE

Tags: org-mode

I maintain shopping list in org-mode. Completed purchases I mark as DONE (`C-c C-t`), later I archive records with:

```
(defun my-org-archive-file (path)
  "Move marked by `org-done-keywords' entries to archive file.
.
Archive file name constructed by `my-org-archive-location'."
  (let ( (archive (my-org-archive-location path))
         entry-re entry-done-re
         entry-beg entry-end )
    (unless archive
      (error "'%s' looks like a non-org file..." path))
    (save-excursion
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect path)
        (org-set-regexps-and-options)
        (setq entry-re "^\\* "
              entry-done-re (concat "^\\* *" (mapconcat 'regexp-quote org-done-keywords "\\|") " "))
        (kill-new "")
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward entry-done-re nil t)
          (setq entry-beg (line-beginning-position))
          (if (re-search-forward entry-re nil t)
              (beginning-of-line)
            (goto-char (point-max)))
          (setq entry-end (point))
          (let ( (last-command 'kill-region) )
            (kill-region entry-beg entry-end))
          )
        (when (> (length (car kill-ring)) 0)
          (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect archive)
            (goto-char (point-max))
            (insert ?\n)
            (yank)
            (save-buffer))
          (save-buffer) )))))
```

Some purchases might fail and I want additional indication for it as `FAILED` but with semantic of `DONE`.

**What variable and how should I update to add extra *terminal* status `FAILED` in addition to `DONE`?** I;d like to preserve above archiving function operational (seems that requires `org-done-keywords` is populated properly by Org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following code, seems it works as I wished:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "|" "DONE" "FAILED")))
```

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if you wish.